# Having problems plotting Lineplot in seaborn library

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

[image]I would please like to request some help here. I am using seaborn in Python to plot multiple line plots but unfortunately, I keep getting errors. However, when I used the preloaded datasets in seaborn like fMRI datasets, it went well.

Below is the code I used:

```py
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv("ucc.csv")
df

df = sns.load_dataset("ucc")
ax = sns.lineplot(x="hours", y="viability", data=ucc)
```

This is the error that I get whenever I run the above code:

```sh
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-07a022f8777e> in <module>
----> 1 df = sns.load_dataset("ucc")
      2 ax = sns.lineplot(x="hours", y="viability", data=ucc)

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/seaborn/utils.py in load_dataset(name, cache, data_home, **kws)
    434                                   os.path.basename(full_path))
    435         if not os.path.exists(cache_path):
--> 436             urlretrieve(full_path, cache_path)
    437         full_path = cache_path
    438 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    245     url_type, path = splittype(url)
    246 
--> 247     with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
    248         headers = fp.info()
    249 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 
    533         return response

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
    640             response = self.parent.error(
--> 641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 
    643         return response

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    567         if http_err:
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 
    571 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    501         for handler in handlers:
    502             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 503             result = func(*args)
    504             if result is not None:
    505                 return result

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me break down what you have done so that perhaps you can understand better what is going on; See the comments inline with your code.

```py
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv("ucc.csv"). # Loads the csv file locally into a pandas dataframe
df  # Prints the head of that dataframe

# This command specifically loads datasets from [github](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data) by name; It's for testing. You are getting the 404 error because there is no ucc dataset in the github repository.
df = sns.load_dataset("ucc")

# This is the command that actually creates the plot. You are referencing a variable 'ucc' that you have not declared and you would get an error if you had not already excepted from the prior 404.
ax = sns.lineplot(x="hours", y="viability", data=ucc)
```

I don't have your dataset so I can not give you an exact example, however, using the mpg dataset downloaded locally I can give you at least a working example of what I believe you are trying to accomplish.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('mpg.csv')
ax = sns.lineplot(x=df['model_year'], y=df['mpg'])
```

[image: Matplotlib Lineplot of MPG over Model Year]

Comment: Thank you so much Professor/Dr. I am actually being very new to using seaborn for data science. I tried uploading the datasets here but couldn't find the right way to do so. Basically, the datasets contains four columns "category", "hours" which have 0, 24, 48, 72 and 96 hours, "viability" for each of the time, and "cells" which contains eight (8) different cell lines. I want plot a lineplot for x=hours and y= viability with errorbars using Seaborn. I will be glad to learn more from you. I wish I will find a way to attach the datasets. Thank you once again Sir.

Comment: Dear Professor/Dr. JerodG, I have just added the snapshot of the datasets above to observe how the datasets are arranged. I couldn't find where to attach you the datasets I would have done so. Thank you in anticipation for your kind positive response.